# How to read button tag in IBAction?

Tags: objective-c, ibaction

I have button:

```
...

UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
rightButton.tag = myCustomNumber;
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
```

And here is IBAction:

```
..
-(IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender{

    // here I want to NSLOG button tag

}
...
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just cast your sender to UIControl

```
-(IBAction)showDetails:(UIControl *)sender {

    // here I want to NSLOG button tag
    NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If showDetails is always called from a `UIButton` you could change the name of the method to:

```
- (IBAction)showDetails:(UIButton *)sender {
        NSLog(@"%i", (UIButton *)sender.tag);
}
```

Remember to perform this change also at the interface file

However, if you use showDetails from different IBAction elements you will have to introspect and check if sender is a UIButton:

```
- (IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender {
       if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]
       NSLog(@"%i", (UIButton *)sender.tag);
}
```

**Edit:** The reason of doing this is that in the way you wrote the code, sender has a dynamic type `id` and it doesn't have any `tag` property.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSLog("%d", (UIButton *)sender.tag);
```

sender is an UIButton object. hope it helps. happy coding :)